# Dynamically Binding parameters to push to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have a lot of historical data I'm pushing to SQL. As a stop gap I'm coding this in VBA first. I open the `.xlsx` file, put the headers into an array to determine what SQL table the data goes into. Then I'm using solution #3 from [INSERT INTO statement from Excel to SQL Server Table using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897825/insert-into-statement-from-excel-to-sql-server-table-using-vba) to base my SQL string on. I'm throwing an automation error at the `.parameters.append` line. Is there another way to dynamically append the parameters? Or is this just incorrect syntax? I appreciate any help!

Code:

```
'creates db connection
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & wbk.FullName & ";" & "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0;Mode=ReadWrite;"
    .Open
End With

sqlStr = "INSERT INTO DB_Name." & tblname & " ("

For i = 1 To UBound(hdrary)
    If i <> UBound(hdrary) Then
        sqlStr = sqlStr & hdrary(i, 1) & ", "
    Else
        sqlStr = sqlStr & hdrary(i, 1) & ") VALUES ("
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To UBound(hdrary)
    If i <> UBound(hdrary) Then
        sqlStr = sqlStr & "?, "
    Else
        sqlStr = sqlStr & "?)"
    End If
Next i

'Statement follows this example:
'strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & Database_Name & ".[dbo]." & Table_Name & _
'         "    ([Audit], [Audit Type], [Claim Received Date], [Date Assigned], [Date Completed]," & _
'         "     [Analyst], [Customer], [ID], [Affiliate], [Facility], [DEA], [Acct Number], [Wholesaler]," & _
'         "     [Vendor], [Product], [NDC], [Ref], [Claimed Contract], [Claimed Contract Cost]," & _
'         "     [Contract Price Start Date], [Contract Price End Date], [Catalog Number], [Invoice Number], [Invoice Date]," & _
'         "     [Chargeback ID], [Contract Indicator], [Unit Cost],[WAC], [Potential Credit Due]," & _
'         "     [Qty], [Spend],[IP-DSH indicator Y/N], [DSH and/or HRSA Number], [Unique GPO Code]," & _
'         "     [Comment],[ResCode],[Correct Cost],[CRRB CM],[CRRB Rebill],[CRRB Date])" & _
'         " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?," _
'         "         ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

lastrow = wks.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

sys.Close

For i = 2 To lastrow
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    With cmd
      .ActiveConnection = conn   ' CONNECTION OBJECT
      .CommandText = sqlStr        ' SQL STRING
      .CommandType = adCmdText

      ' BINDING PARAMETERS
        For j = 1 To UBound(hdrary)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("s" & hdrary(j, 1), adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, wks.Cells(i, j))
            .Execute
        Next j
    End With

    Set cmd = Nothing
Next i
```

UPDATED: Based on @joel-coehoorn's answer, I updated the command and deleted the `wbk.close`. I'm throwing a "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal." on the line `cmd.Parameters(j).Value = wks.Cells(i, j).Value`

```
'create command object
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn   ' CONNECTION OBJECT
    .CommandText = sqlStr        ' SQL STRING
    .CommandType = adCmdText
End With

'pre-binds parameters
For j = 1 To UBound(hdrary)
    Set k = cmd.CreateParameter(Chr(34) & hdrary(j, 1) & Chr(34), adVarChar, adParamInput, 255)
    cmd.Parameters.Append k
Next j

'loops through mm worksheet by row
For i = 2 To lastrow

    'SET PARAMETER VALUES
    For j = 1 To UBound(hdrary)
        cmd.Parameters(j).Value = wks.Cells(i, j).Value
    Next j
    
    'RUN THE SQL COMMAND
    cmd.Execute
Next i

Set cmd = Nothing
```

Comment: How is `wks` defined? You close workbook at `wbk.Close` before parameter looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My VBA is more than a little rusty, so there's likely a mistake in here, but I do believe this will get you to a better place.

That disclaimer out of the way, a `.` is just another binary operator, and so I think the space in

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter
```

is not doing all the work you think it is, in that it's not equivalent to

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter
```

but rather

```
cmd.Parameters.Append.CreateParameter
```

which of course is not a thing.

You probably need to do something like this instead:

```
Dim p
For j = 1 To UBound(hdrary)
    Set p = .CreateParameter("s" & hdrary(j, 1), adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, wks.Cells(i, j))
    .Parameters.Append p
Next j
.Execute
```

*Note we don't call `.Execute` until we finish creating all the parameters.*

Additionally, this code is itself inside a loop. You really don't need to recreate `cmd` or all those parameters again on every loop iteration. Rather, you should create the command and parameters **once**, and then only update the parameters' `.Value` properties inside the loop.

```
' ...

sys.Close

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn   ' CONNECTION OBJECT
cmd.CommandText = sqlStr        ' SQL STRING
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

' PRE-BINDING PARAMETERS
Dim p
For j = 1 To UBound(hdrary)
    Set p = cmd.CreateParameter("s" & hdrary(j, 1), adVarChar, adParamInput, 255)
    cmd.Parameters.Append p
Next j

' LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW
For i = 2 To lastrow

    'SET PARAMETER VALUES
    For j = 1 To UBound(hdrary)   
        cmd.Parameters(j-1).Value = wks.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    
    'RUN THE SQL COMMAND
    cmd.Execute
Next i
Set cmd = Nothing
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I have updated my code (i used k instead of p since I already had that variant available). I noticed I was referencing ```wks``` which was in a closed workbook. I removed the ```wbk.close``` statement. I am throwing an "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal." I'll update the OP with the latest, Thank you so much

Comment: @ChrisH. it's possible `cmd.Parameters` is a 0-indexed collection.

Comment: using a zero based index populates the parameters in the collection with the correct values.  That's awesome! Thank you!!! Google tells me that that error typically is a missing value/field in the database. So I'm looking there next to make sure the columns are what they are supposed to be.

Comment: Updated the answer to use the 0-index, since that was confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Joel-Coehoorn here is the final code!

```
'creates db connection
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & wbk.FullName & ";" & "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0;Mode=ReadWrite;"
    .Open
End With

sqlStr = "INSERT INTO DB_Name." & tblname & " ("

'puts in columns
For i = 1 To UBound(hdrary)
    If i <> UBound(hdrary) Then
        sqlStr = sqlStr & hdrary(i, 1) & ", "
    Else
        sqlStr = sqlStr & hdrary(i, 1) & ") VALUES ("
    End If
Next i

'placeholders for VALUES
For i = 1 To UBound(hdrary)
    If i <> UBound(hdrary) Then
        sqlStr = sqlStr & "?, "
    Else
        sqlStr = sqlStr & "?)"
    End If
Next i

'Statement follows this example:
'strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & Database_Name & ".[dbo]." & Table_Name & _
'         "    ([Audit], [Audit Type], [Claim Received Date], [Date Assigned], [Date Completed]," & _
'         "     [Analyst], [Customer], [ID], [Affiliate], [Facility], [DEA], [Acct Number], [Wholesaler]," & _
'         "     [Vendor], [Product], [NDC], [Ref], [Claimed Contract], [Claimed Contract Cost]," & _
'         "     [Contract Price Start Date], [Contract Price End Date], [Catalog Number], [Invoice Number], [Invoice Date]," & _
'         "     [Chargeback ID], [Contract Indicator], [Unit Cost],[WAC], [Potential Credit Due]," & _
'         "     [Qty], [Spend],[IP-DSH indicator Y/N], [DSH and/or HRSA Number], [Unique GPO Code]," & _
'         "     [Comment],[ResCode],[Correct Cost],[CRRB CM],[CRRB Rebill],[CRRB Date])" & _
'         " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?," _
'         "         ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

lastrow = wks.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print sqlStr

sys.Close

'create command object
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn   ' CONNECTION OBJECT
    .CommandText = sqlStr        ' SQL STRING
    .CommandType = adCmdText
End With

'pre-binds parameters
For j = 1 To UBound(hdrary)
    Set k = cmd.CreateParameter(Chr(34) & hdrary(j, 1) & Chr(34), adVarChar, adParamInput, 255)
    cmd.Parameters.Append k
Next j

'loops through worksheet by row
For i = 2 To lastrow

    'sets parameter values and accounts for 0 based array
    For j = 0 To cmd.Parameters.count - 1
        cmd.Parameters(j).Value = wks.Cells(i, j + 1).Value
    Next j
    
    'RUN THE SQL COMMAND
    cmd.Execute
Next i

Set cmd = Nothing
```